# Where can I read Tantric texts in English

Tags: scripture, tantra, translation-request, resource

Where can I read Tantric texts? Is there any online pdf? I want the mantra in English and its meaning. Are there any commentaries by a Proper Guru?

Comment: Quite a decent amount of Tantrika texts are available online at www.archive.org but you should know what book you are searching for. And you must have a strong grasp on basic Sanskrit in order to read them as those texts don't always come with translations.

Comment: Yeah most of the books are in Hindi or Sanskrit, I needed a English version of it

Comment: @Shashaank There's a good amount of Tantras in English here: https://www.sacred-texts.com/tantra/

Comment: Thank you @HariharaVishnumShivah